# How to select Case Class Object as DataFrame in Kafka-Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spark-structured-streaming

I have a case class:

```
case class clickStream(userid:String, adId :String, timestamp:String)
```

instance of which I wish to send with KafkaProducer as :

```
val record = new ProducerRecord[String,clickStream](
  "clicktream",
  "data",
  clickStream(Random.shuffle(userIdList).head, Random.shuffle(adList).head, new Date().toString).toString
)
producer.send(record)
```

which sends record as string perfectly as expected in the TOPIC queue:

```
clickStream(user5,ad2,Sat Jul 18 20:48:53 IST 2020)
```

However, the problem is at Consumer end:

```
val clickStreamDF = spark.readStream
.format("kafka")
.options(kafkaMap)
.option("subscribe","clicktream")
.load()
 

clickStreamDF 
.select($"value".as("string"))
.as[clickStream]       //trying to leverage DataSet APIs conversion
.writeStream
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
.format("console")
.option("truncate","false")
.start()
.awaitTermination()
```

Apparently using **.as[clickStream]** API does not work as Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`userid`' given input columns: [value];
```

This is what **[value]** column contains :

```
    Batch: 2
-------------------------------------------
+----------------------------------------------------+
|value                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|clickStream(user3,ad11,Sat Jul 18 20:59:35 IST 2020)|
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried using **Custom Serializer** as **value.serializer** and **value.deserializer**

But facing a different issue of **ClassNotFoundException** in my directory structure.

I have 3 questions:

***How Kafka uses Custom Deserializer class here to parse the object?***

I do not fully understand the concept of **Encoders** and ***how that can be used in this case?***

***What will be the best approach to send/receive Custom Case Class Objects with Kafka?***

Answer (score 1):

As you are passing `clickStream` object data as `string` to kafka & spark will read same string, In spark you have to parse & extract required fields from `clickStream(user3,ad11,Sat Jul 18 20:59:35 IST 2020)`

Check below code.

```
clickStreamDF 
.select(split(regexp_extract($"value","\\(([^)]+)\\)",1),"\\,").as("value"))
.select($"value"(0).as("userid"),$"value"(1).as("adId"),$"value"(2).as("timestamp"))
.as[clickStream] # Extract all fields from the value string & then use .as[clickStream] option. I think this line is not required as data already parsed to required format. 
.writeStream
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
.format("console")
.option("truncate","false")
.start()
.awaitTermination()
```

Sample How to parse `clickStream` string data.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+---------------------------------------------------+
|value                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|clickStream(user5,ad2,Sat Jul 18 20:48:53 IST 2020)|
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> df
.select(split(regexp_extract($"value","\\(([^)]+)\\)",1),"\\,").as("value"))
.select($"value"(0).as("userid"),$"value"(1).as("adId"),$"value"(2).as("timestamp"))
.as[clickStream]
.show(false)

+------+----+----------------------------+
|userid|adId|timestamp                   |
+------+----+----------------------------+
|user5 |ad2 |Sat Jul 18 20:48:53 IST 2020|
+------+----+----------------------------+
```

What will be the best approach to send/receive Custom Case Class Objects with Kafka?

Try to convert your case class to `json` or `avro` or `csv` then send message to kafka & read same message using spark.